# How to read and output characters without using Array or String in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I should read an user input using `System.in.read()`, save this into a `char` or `int` variable and output the user input in *reversed order*. I should read the input so long as the user is not entering `"#"`

Do you have some ideas how to do this? Sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int inChar;
        System.out.println("Input:");
        try {
            inChar = System.in.read();
            System.out.print("Output: ");
            System.out.println(inChar); // I only get numbers here
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error reading from user");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe a while Loop can help?

Comment: Did you tell your colleague that "Challenge accepted, I'll let the people on StackOverflow solve this"?

Comment: How should I do this when the output should look like:
Input: a
b
c
#
Output: cba

How can I cast a int to String?

Comment: @Kayaman I have a challenge in my college, not my colleague. Sorry ... :D

Comment: @maxir200 you don't need to lie about homework here. It's perfectly acceptable to ask for *help* with homework, but we can't *write* your homework because that would just be silly.

Comment: @maxir200, as already suggested, use a while loop and read input characters. Once `#` is met, break from the loop and do the rest of the job.

Comment: Use `Character.toString((char) inChar);` and you'll figure out the rest.

Comment: @DevilsHnd no need to use `Character.toString`. Just `System.out.print((char) inChar)`.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException - Indeed, however it is still good to note the Character class.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in this task.

How to read user input until the '#' is pressed and how to reverse the char array (String).

Check this out

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String chars = "";
        char inChar = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter Character and press Enter: ");

        while (inChar!='#') {
            inChar = (char)System.in.read();
            if (inChar=='\n'){
                continue;
            }
            chars += inChar;
        }
        System.out.println("Input: " + chars);
        System.out.print("Output: ");
        for (int i=chars.length()-2; i>=0; i--){
            System.out.print(chars.charAt(i));
        }
    }
```

Edit: Thanks @DevilsHnd. Code updated with System.in.read() in place of Scanner.

In the while loop, the code reads user input until '#' key is pressed. Java cannot read keypresses unless you use GUI (swing, awt) or a JNI C++ library. So code reads user input when Enter is pressed.

If user enters # then the loop breaks. For all the other characters the character is added to the final String. As System.in.read() reads also new lines (\n) the code does not add them to the final string.

For the second problem, the code iterates so many times as the length of the final String and prints the characters starting from the last one.
Note that the iteration starts with character at position length-2, this is because the last character of the String is '#', therefore this should not be printed at the output.

Comment: I thought the OP said he's not supposed to use `String` or arrays.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException OP said to store the input in char or int, did not say not to use Objects or Arrays. _Reverse order_ applies to a collection of 2 or more characters, the problem cannot be solved without using a data type or Object holding more than one character.